WordPress JetEngine - Featured Image Listing Grid, Hide Field When No Featured Image Is Loaded
I have a slider made with a listing grid that displays the featured images of the posts in that section of the page. Some posts don't have a featured image loaded, and the corresponding slide in the slider appears empty. I would like to hide the posts in the slider that don't have featured images loaded.
I've tried using dynamic visibility but haven't been successful. Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve this? Thanks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
